# SSIS executing wrong (old) package version

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server Agent Job executing a file-system-deployed SSIS package via CmdExec & the 32 bit DTExec. However, the most recent version of the package version is not executing.

The change I've made is within a Script Task. I've made sure to Build within the VSTA editor before closing, etc.

I've verified this is the problem by putting the expected version in the command line parameters, so the task fails: `/VERIFYVERSIONID "\"{1F870663-1898-4A30-B4A8-226817D1755F}\""`

Is there a cache that can be cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to see here, move along..

I'm doing new child package testing on a server hosting multiple environments shared by my dev team, and we're in the process of shuffling things around. The job in question is one of a few identical ones and the path to the package got changed.

This is a 'master' package that dynamically executes child packages based on values read from a queue which is why it didn't occur to me to check the path.

Noob oversight.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to change the executiontype for the SQL job to be Operating System (CMDEXE) and provide the path to the dtexec file for SSIS to use as the executable.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe /FILE "c:\path\to\my\ssis\package\myssispackage.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E

By calling the dtsx specifically you can point to the 32 or 64 bit version. You can also revert to a previous version of SSIS (dtexec) if you have those installed on your executing server.

I recently upgraded some of my packages to SSIS 2012 and had to use the new version for the packages to be executed by dtexec. That resolved my issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am executing with CmdExec. It's not the SSIS version that is the problem, but the version of the package itself.

Comment: Package version, meaning 32 vs 64 bits?

Comment: Ah, no. The `VersionGUID` of the package when you right-click empty space on the design canvas and select Properties. In the command line you supply the version you want DTExec to run (or fail if it doesn't match) with `/VERIFYVERSIONID "\"{1F870663-1898-4A30-B4A8-226817D1755F}\""` for instance.

Comment: Ok, now I'm with you. So do you get the same results when you execute via the job as when you execute via command line?

Comment: I was not, no. Manual execution, debugging, and command line were all working as expected. But .. that was because the location of the package configured in the job got changed. (See my answer above)

Comment: Ok, I've misunderstood the post. Do you have an error message that you can share?

Comment: There was no error message until I forced the version verification - the new code in the script task I modified was simply not executing. At first it appeared the reason was SSIS was somehow caching the package, but it turned out the Job Step got modified to point to another package location so the package I was updating was never even running.